# Exponent is to exponentiation as _______ is to tetration

Tags: notation, terminology, tetration

Would it be tetrand, tetrant, or something else?

Comment: Not sure people care too much about this. Why do you need this? Perhaps just adopt a word and go with it.

Comment: See [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Terminology) : "The parameter $a$ may be called the *base*-parameter, while the parameter $n$ may be called the *height*-parameter."

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I don't need it, I find nomenclature itself interesting.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You are clearly a better reader than I. Happy to accept as an answer if you make it one.

Comment: FYI, I've called it the [tetrated exponent](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tetrated+exponent%22+%22Renfro%22&filter=0) in some early 2000s sci.math posts.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: once you are convinced to use the idea of "height" for that parameter, it would be consequent (and for instance I do it in my discussions) to use *h* for its default variable/index.

Comment: Another idea just coming to mind: "iterator" for the "height"(see other comments), "iterand" for that which is iterated - possibly a good choice for the "base"-parameter, but as well possibly a good choice for the initial $x_0$ argument (from where iteration starts)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: people who care about tetration probably do. Just like people interested in symplectic geometry care about symplectic *forms*.

Comment: ............. "_Tetponent_"?

Answer (score 0):

When I first (ca 2007) came in contact with (what I later called) "exponentialtower" and which is even in its un-generalized form commonly called "tetration", this occured under the name "powertower" (for instance see mathworld). It seemed very natural for me to use the term (iteration-) "***height***" for the extend of iteration of that imagination of increasing a "powertower". After that, to use the letter "*h*" as its default shortcut/variable is again natural. For instance in the "tetration-forum" (founded at 2007) the term "height" has become a much common use.
*(By this I consequently don't like/use the term* "super-log()" *or* "slog()" *for the function which tells us the required height of iteration from one $z_0$ to $z_h$ but use simply $\text{hgh}()$ as that function in article and software)*

*disclaimer: this is only amateur-mathematics, no journal-publication or academic practice behind this*

---

Additional remark: in a comment, if I recall correctly, there was a discussion whether exponentiation should be seen as "iterated multiplication" at all (as well as in its generalized to fractional iteration-"heights") but as a genuine operation (I think it was MSE/MO-user Qiaochu Yuan) and similarly for tetration, if at all, should also a more genuine operation be formulated - apart from the basic idea of iteration of an exponentiation. I like this idea much, but such a genuine operation has not been formulated yet. ***If*** it is formulated then the term *height* might be replaced by some more appropriate name - but I don't see any ansatz for this so far...